# How to block IP by interacting with Firewall in JAVA?

Tags: networking, firewall, java, springframework

I have built an Intrusion Detection System in JAVA. I have a web interface which shows a black listed IP. IP's are categorized as Web attcks, SIP attacks, SSH attacks, Probing and Malware.
Now I am required to block this IP which falls in any of these categories. Is there a way to do it in java , by interacting with firewall? 
All wincap lib or wrappers dont work in inline mode so any way to do it ?

Comment: Well, what firewall? You haven't specified.

Comment: Am sorry for that ! 
It can be windows firewall , I just to need to complete this project so any firewall related will do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

If it's a windows firewall you can use java to send powershell firewall configuration commands to it.

Example: permit ICMP both internally and externally:

```
Import-Module NetSecurity

New-NetFirewallRule -Name Allow_Ping -DisplayName “Allow Ping”`

  -Description “Packet Internet Groper ICMPv4” `

  -Protocol ICMPv4 -IcmpType 8 -Enabled True -Profile Any -Action Allow
```

You save the code as a .ps1 and call it from within java just like trying to run any .exe.

Comment: Thanks for replying , would u elaborate it a bit ? Or give me any link !

Comment: I have added an example that allows ping through FW. You'll have to document yourself a little on powershell (check Technet) but once you have the basics, you can make powershell files for any firewall exception command you may want to add.